# How to change columns used by default by laravel sanctum (email and password) by custom ones?

Tags: laravel, authentication, guard

I just installed laravel, sanctrum, livewire as new auth system. I need to use an already created table for users.
I am trying to change my **User** model for custom one. Thing is that this other model have no defaults columns (email and password) so I need to personalize how sanctrum is using this.
I already create de Model and changed in config/auth.php the default model:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
        ],
```

Then I am getting error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `USUARIOS` where `email` = dgb1982uk@gmail.com limit 1)
```

I know is not too much info, but probably someone had before to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the structure of the Usuario table. Is there an email column, or is the email field something else

Comment: The email column have a different name. Thatś all the problem. But I already solved. I will post the solution when i get time. Thanks for be envolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in files of the folder App\Actions\Fortify.
All this files have the logic functions that use fields for login and password traitments.

Per example:

App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php file make the validation for the register form and create a new User. So, changing there your custom names for fields will make to work the registration form in sanctrum.

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return Usuario::create([
            'custom_name_for_name' => $input['name'],
            'custom_name_for_email' => $input['email'],
            'custom_name_for_password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

So, in resume:

1- We need to create the Custom User Model.

2- Change in config/auth.php the default model.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
        ],
```

3- Then modify fields names in files of App\Actions\Fortify